# Gradle build transform error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>
> > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
> >     bolts/AggregateException.class

build.gradle file

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion '25.0.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.app"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}


}



dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.2.0'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Update your facebook SDK and appcompat version

Answer (score 0):

Change `compile` `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3`' to `compile` `'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'` and rebuild the project.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding following code in app level grade (build.gradle) :

```
dexOptions {
javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
preDexLibraries = false
}
```

Also make sure you have set name property of manifest's application tag as MultidexApplication.

Answer (score 0):

Try this codes:

```
compile ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'){
exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts',
        module: 'bolts-tasks'
exclude group: 'com.parse.bolts',
        module: 'bolts-applinks';}
```